# How to run android eye detection code in background

Tags: android, opencv, eye-detection

I have implemented android eye detection application.Now i want to run it as a background application.How it's possible?

Source code for eye detection application - http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-updated-for-opencv-2-4-6/

Comment: Do you mean to run you app in background even if you app is killed ?

Comment: No. I have implemented another application.when that application is open, i want to run eye detection application without giving any preview.